# Creating 3 horizontal sticky bars that stick at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created one fixed navbar. kept it simple as it ws fixed at the top. Now there are two other bar that should stick under it as the page scrolls instead of disapearing under it. Im am try this but cant get the bar to stay it replaces it.

js

```
var stickyHeaders = (function() {

  var $window = $(window),
      $stickies;

  var load = function(stickies) {

    if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

      $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

        var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');

        $thisSticky
            .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
            .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
              .parent()
              .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());             
      });

      $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {
          _whenScrolling();     
      });
    }
  };

  var _whenScrolling = function() {

    $stickies.each(function(i) {            

      var $thisSticky = $(this),
          $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

      if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {        

        var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
            $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

        $thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

        if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

          $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
        }

      } else {

        var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

        $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

        if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

          $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    load: load
  };
})();

$(function() {
  stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));
});
```

This works but keeps deleting the last fixed stick instead of staying attached.

css

```
.followMeBar {
  background: #e64a19;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.followMeBar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.followMeBar.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}


/* For aesthetics only ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 200 1.2em "Segoe UI Light", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  background: #039be4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  strong {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Black";
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

.explanation {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  p {
    max-width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="followMeBar">A</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">B</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">C</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">D</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">E</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">F</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">G</div>
```

Comment: why not you prefer using drop-down?

Comment: in what way? Is there a better way of doing this?